# How to solve the recursive complexity for T(n) = T(n/2) + 2^n by iteration method?

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

I'm trying to find the upper bound & lower bound , which is probably O(2^n)

### T(n) = 1 for n<=4

I know that the general organ is:

T(n) = T(n/2^(i+1)) + sum from i=0 to k of 2^(n/2^i)

---

from here i dont know how to proceed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some problem with your notation. The general organ should be:

`T(n) = T(n/2^(i+1)) + sum from k=0 to i of 2^(n/2^k)`

After this step, we let `i = log(2, n) - 1`, so that `T(n/2^(i+1)) = T(1)`.

Therefore, `T(n) = T(1) + sum from k = 0 to (log(2, n) - 1) of 2^(n/2^k)`.

Note that `sum from k = 0 to (log(2, n) - 1) of 2^(n/2^k)` is `2^n + 2^(n/2) + 2^(n/4) + ...`, which is smaller than `2^n + 2^(n-1) + 2^(n-2) + ...`. However, the latter stuff is `2^(n+1) - 1`. So the former stuff is something between `2^n` and `2^(n+1)`. Therefore, the **sum** is `O(2^n)`.

Then `T(n) = O(2^n)`.

Comment: Ok, why the latter stuff is 2^(n+1)-1 and not 2^(n/log(2, n)-1)?

Comment: Suppose n is 3. I use `2^n + 2^(n-1) + 2^(n-2) + ...` to refer to `2^3 + 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0` which equals to 15, which also equals to `2^(n+1)-1`